# Newbie Syncfusion Chart not showing bars

Tags: charts, blazor, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion charts for the first time.  Their getting started instructions are very clear and I have my first chart on a Blazor component.  The chart grid, titles, and x-axis displays fine, the y-axis is scaled properly..... however, no bars or lines show to display my data.

Thanks for your help.  Code is below.

```
    @using System.Runtime.CompilerServices
    @using Syncfusion.Blazor
    @using Syncfusion.Blazor.Charts
    @implements IDisposable
    
    <div style="position:absolute; text-align:center; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; font-size:1.2vh;">
        <div style="height:60%;">
            <SfChart Title="Messages Sent/Received">
    
                <ChartPrimaryXAxis Title="Time Interval" ValueType="Syncfusion.Blazor.Charts.ValueType.Category"></ChartPrimaryXAxis>
    @*            <ChartPrimaryYAxis Title="Messages" ValueType="Syncfusion.Blazor.Charts.ValueType.Double"></ChartPrimaryYAxis>*@
                <ChartTooltipSettings Enable="true"></ChartTooltipSettings>
                <ChartSeriesCollection>
                    <ChartSeries DataSource="@SentMessages" XName="SeriesDate" YName="SeriesYValue" Type="ChartSeriesType.Line">
                    </ChartSeries>
                </ChartSeriesCollection>
    
            </SfChart>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    @code {
        public class SeriesType
        {
            public string SeriesDate  { get; set; }      
            public double SeriesYValue { get; set; }
        }
        public List<SeriesType> SentMessages = new List<SeriesType>
        {
            new SeriesType {SeriesDate="8/1/2023", SeriesYValue=4023},
            new SeriesType {SeriesDate="8/2/2023", SeriesYValue=2123},
            new SeriesType {SeriesDate="8/3/2023", SeriesYValue=1823},
            new SeriesType {SeriesDate="8/4/2023", SeriesYValue=2423},
            new SeriesType {SeriesDate="8/5/2023", SeriesYValue=923}
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may occur due to incorrect script references. As a suggestion you can check whether the script is properly referenced in the _Host.cshtml file for Blazor Server or index.html for Blazor Web Assembly. It is important to ensure that the script is referenced correctly to avoid any rendering issues. A sample and screenshot is attached for your reference.

For Individual package script reference:

```
<script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Core/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For whole package script reference:

```
<script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For CDN script reference:

```
<script src=https://cdn.syncfusion.com/blazor/22.1.38/syncfusion-blazor.min.js type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SyncfusionChart-834673013.zip

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz1jS.png)

UG for Getting Started: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/chart/getting-started

UG for Script references: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/common/adding-script-references